# Can't find my schedules in Report Manager

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We are using reporting services with the Schedules feature, but somehow we can't see older schedules that we made a few months ago. When I go to **My Subscriptions** in the upper right corner, we only see the reports that were made in the last 3 months. All the other ones (and the one I need) aren't there. Even when I go to the report in question, it doesn't show the subscriptions I am looking for.

However, when I go to the database that reporting services uses, I can see all the reports, even the ones from more than 3 months ago. I used this query:

```
SELECT      dbo.catalog.[Path], 
  dbo.catalog.Name,
  s.Description,        
  u.UserName,       
  s.DeliveryExtension
FROM catalog with (nolock)
JOIN dbo.Subscriptions s with (nolock)  
  ON s.Report_OID = dbo.Catalog.ItemID
JOIN dbo.Users u WITH (nolock)  
  ON u.UserID = s.OwnerID
ORDER BY dbo.catalog.[Path],s.Description
```

All the schedules have the same owner.

How come I can't see a lot of my schedules on the report server "site" and how do I find them?

Comment: Can you see the schedules in the report manager UI and/or do the schedules still fire off as previously scheduled?

Comment: No, that's what my question is about, I can't see it in any UI, only in the database. A few of the reports were fired off as little as 2 weeks ago, but the status of the last run is Pending in the database.